# eclipse for android development is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I want to learn Android development for that I install JDK and eclipse ADT bundle but when I start eclipse it starts eclipse JUNO instate of android development kit logo.

Comment: Are you downloading the right 32-bit or 64-bit version for your PC?

Comment: Well that shouldn't be a problem. Maybe you just have to create new Android Project? I don't think that logo on splash screen have to be different to ADT working properly.

Comment: yes . for begginer i want to start with basic project

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue, the only workaround right now is to manually download Eclipse (4.4 is the latest), and install ADT manually. You can find instructions on how to install ADT here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the adt bundle or simply eclipse ADT?
if you have installed the adt bundle then you simply needed to install JDK and start working on projects by creating new projects from File>New>Android APplication Projects.
or if you have installed the eclipse Adt then you will need to install Jdk, Android SDK etc

Comment: i download adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624 from android developer site

Comment: then i bit u are not needed to face any issue if u installed java jdk!

Comment: I m not getting what i really want. i start eclipse from adt-bundel->eclipse->eclipse.exe but it starts with normal Eclipse instate of Android development kit splash screen.

Comment: event i try on eclipse JUNO but no option for android application there

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you. It starts from the installing eclipse and go on.[Installing eclipse with adt tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6xLbETRijw)